# Conditional differential entropy of sum of Gaussians

Tags: pr.probability, entropy, gaussian

Is it possible to give an expression for the conditional differential entropy $h(A+B\mid C+D),$ where $A,B,C,D$ are normally distributed with known standard deviations $σ_A,\ldots,σ_D$ and where **all but $A$ and $C$** are conditinally independent? For $A$ and $C,$ the Pearson’s correlation value $C$ is known. The resulting expression should depend on $σ_A,\ldots,σ_D$ and $C.$
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\si\sigma$The question is stated very poorly. In particular, it is unclear

- how you define the conditional differential entropy
- if $A, B, C, D$ are jointly normal
- if they are zero-mean
- what you mean by "**all but A and C** are conditinally independent"

Assuming that $A, B, C, D$ are jointly normal and zero-mean, $A+B$ and $C+D$ will be jointly normal and zero-mean, and then simple calculations yield
$$h(A+B|C+D)=\ln\si_{A+B}+\frac12(1+\ln(2\pi(1-\rho^2))),$$
where $\si_{A+B}$ is the standard deviation of $A+B$, $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient of $A+B$ and $C+D$,
$$h(X|Y):=-\int_{\mathbb R^2} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ln f_{X|Y}(x|y)\,dx\,dy,$$
$f_{X,Y}$ is the joint pdf of random variables $X$ and $Y$, and  $f_{X|Y}$ is the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y$.

In turn, it is straightforward to express $\si_{A+B}$ and $\rho$ in terms of the variances and covariances of $A, B, C, D$.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Apologies for being very imprecise with my question. Indeed, your assumptions of zero mean and jointly normal distributions are correct. With conditionally independent, I meant that $h(A|B) = h(A)$, $h(B|A) = h(B)$, etc... 
And finally, I guess you have a different definition of conditional differential entropy, since I would assume $h(X|Y)$ to be $h(X|Y)=ln(\sigma_X \sqrt{2 \pi e}) + \frac{1}{2} ln(1-\rho^2)$ for normal distributions.

Comment: @ChristianWagner : Your expression for the conditional differential entropy in the jointly normal case is the same as mine, with an easy rearrangement.

Comment: @ChristianWagner : Do you have a further response to the answer and my comment?